# Move Method Refactoring in Eclipse, programmatically, with MoveInstanceMethodProcessor cannot find a target

Tags: refactoring, eclipse-jdt, automated-refactoring

I am trying to automate refactoring tasks. While some refactoring tasks work with reusage of refactoring API (LTK and JDT-based), Move Method doesn't. Am I missing something with this code:

```
MoveInstanceMethodProcessor processorMM = new MoveInstanceMethodProcessor(method,null);
processorMM.setTargetName(method.getDeclaringType().toString());
IVariableBinding[] candidateTargets = processorMM.getCandidateTargets();
IVariableBinding[] targets= processorMM.getPossibleTargets();

processorMM.setTarget(targets[1]);
MoveRefactoring refactoringMM = new MoveRefactoring(processorMM);
RefactoringStatus statusMM = refactoringMM.checkAllConditions(monitor);
Change changeMM = refactoringMM.createChange(monitor);
undoChange = changeMM.perform(monitor);
```

These candidateTargets and targets are always empty, and no possible target can be found even if I loop through the all methods in the project. Some method can be moved manually, but my code doesn't find them.

Am I missing something? What is the proper way of getting target for Move Method refactoring?

NOTE: I want to avoid, as much as possible, writing my own code for anything that I can feel is already there.

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.structure.MoveInstanceMethodProcessor` is an **internal** class and is therefore not part of the JDT API - [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: What is, then, more appropriate way to reuse Move Method refactoring?

Comment: It seems that general MoveDescriptor will do the job with small trick on members to move.